# How to do internationalization/localization using MS Fluent UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I want to build a multilingual dashboard using Fabric/Fluent UI. I couldn't find anything in the docs/wiki related to internationalization or localization except RTL support.

Is there a recommended way to do this with Fluent UI? Or would I need to use 3rd party react internationalization libraries like https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this on the Fluent UI github repo, there is no opinionated way or solution from Microsoft for this and we'd need to use a 3rd party solution.